# YouTube API 3.0 on New Developers Console

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to obtain Authorization Credentials for YouTube API 3.0 using the directions on this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application, but when I log into my Google Developers Console, YouTube API 3.0 isn't listed. The list stops with Translate API. Is it somewhere other than the API list?

Comment: screen can help, it's not very clear

Answer (score 0):

It should be listed there!
Under https://console.developers.google.com/project select your project and navigate to "APIs and auth" -> "APIs"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good step-by-step tutorial with pictures about enabling YouTube API in Google console. Under Create your Google API App, it says:
Sign-in to your Google account then go to Google Developer Console at https://console.developers.google.com, then "Enable and manage APIs" in the Getting Started page. A project will be created and you will be forwarded to the API Manager page below. If not, open the left-hand side menu then click on the API Manager link.
A page with a list of Popular APIs categories appears as shown below. Under "YouTube APIs" category click in the first link "YouTube Data API" then click the "Enable" button at the top-left of the page to enable YouTube Data API v3.

http://viduploader3.com/documents/#create_your_google_api_app